# Set PyCharm to scroll slower using mouse wheel

Tags: scroll, pycharm, mousewheel

I am trying to figure out how to set the screen to scroll slower for my mouse wheel, because it basically does a full page down and I can't maintain my bearings in the code.

Is this possible to change, or am I stuck with the current setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible to change, or am I stuck with the current setting?

I just tried this with several settings on Windows and the OS configurations for the mouse take complete precedence over the IDE. PyCharm only has one configuration to smooth the mouse scrolling speed but the impact is negligeable in relation to the underlying OS settings.

Trying the combinations for ["Smooth scrolling" together with "Caret behavior"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-editor-general.html) also has no noticeable impact. Besides this the only other IDE mouse setting is [zoom with mouse](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Zooming_in_the_Editor.html) but that also doesn't impact the editor scrooling speed.

So if the above doesn't work the only alternative left is adjusting the OS mouse settings to fit the IDE.

The mouse scrolling configurations are at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `General` `>` `Scrolling` as shown in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot of PyCharm settings.]